# npm install can't find package.json

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, npm-install

I'm trying to dockerize my django+react app.
Problem is, after I create in my container a directory for `frontend` and try to `RUN npm install`, npm can't find `package.json`. Before `RUN npm install` I switch to `WORKDIR /app/app-name/front` to which I copy this file. Strange for me is that error shows:

```
app    | npm ERR! code ENOENT
app    | npm ERR! syscall open
app    | npm ERR! path /app/label_it/package.json <-------------------------
app    | npm ERR! errno -2
app    | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/label_it/package.json'
app    | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
app    | npm ERR! enoent
```

In this error line, npm points that there is no package.json in `/app/label_it/` directory, which is obvious. Why is that I set `WORKDIR /app/label_it/front` and npm runs in `/app/label_it` ???

I use `docker-compose` to build this image and run container. In my `docker-compose.yaml` I've set a `workdir: /app/label_it` . It might be the case, but why ?

Seems like this compose variable `workdir` overrides every `WORKDIR` command in `Dockerfile`.
Is that the case, or am I missing something ?

EDIT:

I just tried deleting from compose file `workdir: /app/label_it/` and it works perfectly. Still i don't understand.

Dockerifle:

```
FROM python:3

RUN apt-get update -yq \
    && apt-get install curl gnupg -yq \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash \
    && apt-get install nodejs -yq

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN mkdir -p /app/label_it
WORKDIR /app/label_it
COPY requirements.txt /app/label_it
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app/label_it/front
COPY label_it/front/package.json .

RUN npm install -g npm-install-peers
RUN npm install

COPY label_it/ /app/label_it/

COPY scripts/ /app/scripts/

RUN chmod +x /app/scripts/*

# change USER for security

WORKDIR /app/label_it

CMD ["production-script.sh"]
```

docker-compose:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - ./private/posgtesql/data/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: app
    environment:
      - DJANGO_DEBUG=True
      - PATH=/app/scripts:${PATH}
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Comment: If you define the `workingdir` in the `docker run` command, you overwrite the config within the Dockerfile. Docker Compose is a simple solution for the `ducker run` commands. That is the reason why the `docker-compose.yml` overwrites the `workingdir` in the Dockerfile. I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include your actual `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: @Spirit what about `ENV` in Dockerfile ? I'm not getting any envvaraibles in container while setting them in Dockerfile, but with compose I do. Is it the same issue ?

Comment: Are you seeing this error during the build (`docker-compose build`) or does it come from something in your `production-script.sh`?  The `volumes:` hide everything the Dockerfile does in the image's `/app` directory, which includes some amount of rearranging and setup; does deleting that block help?

Comment: @DavidMaze I think it was during image build, because only then Dockerfile is used and might be overriten. As solution, I've deleted `workdir: /app/label_it` in `docker-compose` and was consistent in Dockerfile with it.